# How to get a Json property name of a JsonObject when using System.Text.Json.Nodes namespace in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0

I have a simple Json string

```
{
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value1"
}
```

that I parse to a JsonObject using the System.Text.Json.Nodes namespace with the following line

```
JsonObject obj = JsonNode.Parse(requestBody).AsObject();
```

How can I get the properties names (property1 and property2) of the JsonObject?

If there are alternatives, It would help me

Answer (score 6):

you can try this

```
JsonObject obj = JsonNode.Parse(requestBody).AsObject();
string[] propertyNames = obj.Select(p =>p.Key ).ToArray();
```

result

```
["property1","property2"]
```

or

```
   var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);

    foreach (var property in doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} - {property.Value}");
    }
```

result

```
property1 - value1
property2 - value1
```

or using linq

```
string[] propertyNames = doc.EnumerateObject().Select(p => p.Name ).ToArray();
```